# How to reset or remove Brave Wallet?

Tags: metamask, brave

How to remove Brave browser Wallet? (It is similar to MetaMask but is baked into browser )

Page at brave://wallet/ is asking for password, that I don't remember and I don't need that,
I just need new.

---

Searches give no result so far.

P.S. Source of extensions are at https://github.com/brave/ethereum-remote-client
Issues there are disabled, and it looks like Brave orgnization guide to add issues into main https://github.com/brave/brave-browser repository that have 3k open issues

P.P.S.

https://community.brave.com/t/deleting-crypto-wallet/149327/3 point to https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/10999 that is actually about removing account within wallet.

https://www.reddit.com/r/brave_browser/comments/9y7a06/is_there_a_way_to_delete_a_wallet/ suggest to play with (giving disclaimer) browser data folder

> On you Windows machine, the bulk of your Wallet data is stored in ~/AppData/local/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/userdata/default in a file named ledger_state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: It seems that Brave actually implemented a way to reset the wallet.

Go to Settings > Wallet (in the left column) > Reset Wallet > Type in "Yes"

I've tried to delete different files and found out that after deleting the folder `%LocalAppData%\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\odbfpeeihdkbihmopkbjmoonfanlbfcl` resets the wallet and you can create a new one. But that doesn't reset the whole wallet thing, normally you have to press a button "I understand" before you can create, restore and so on.

So navigate to `chrome://version` to check profile location see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/user_data_dir.md
and then delete/rename `Local Extension Settings\odbfpeeihdkbihmopkbjmoonfanlbfcl` folder, then you can create new wallet. (Of cause old wallet is gone)

Comment: this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I seems not possible currently,

removing Brave Wallet extention is also not possible.
it is open issue
https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/8742

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is to remove C:\Users[your user]\AppData\Local\BraveSoftware.
Then brave lets you setup a new wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled the Crypto Wallet extension. [Crypto Wallet extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k49A.png)

Comment: How did you disable it?

Comment: That is just hiding from eyes, the wallet with forgotten or too simple password stays on.

Comment: @simasjoneliunas, you can go to extensios and disable it. Anyway, I ended up finding another easy way to have my crypto wallet reset as well. I simply created another profile (I have several different profiles now) and did not touch the crypto wallet option. :)

Comment: @paulverest, I hadn't thought about that before. But creating a new profile would solve this problem. (OFF-TOPIC: Another thing that bothers me in Brave is the verified wallet limit.)

Comment: I don't see the extension in the list

Answer (score 0):

In settings -> wallet, where it says 'default cryptocurrency wallet' set that to none, so that it doesn't override any other wallet you want to use.